# Xamarin.Forms - Android requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms project. Here is my MainActivity.cs from the Android part of the project:

```
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Every time I try to test on my device I get an `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException` with the following message: `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` even though I'm not calling `requestFeature()` at all. Here's the stack trace:

```
--- End of managed Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException stack trace ---
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:338)
    at md5f4656b392f6d15b90a32ccb2cb36af91.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md5f4656b392f6d15b90a32ccb2cb36af91.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

I've already tried restarting Xamarin Studio and cleaning/rebuilding my solution. What am I missing?

Edit: Just created a new blank Xamarin.Forms project. It ran perfectly on my device. Still can't get the old project to run though.

Comment: Xamarin Studio has been deprecated in favor of Visual Studio.  If you're really using XS, I'd try updating first

Comment: @Jason I just created a new project in XS which ran fine on my device.

Comment: OK, but you still will no longer receive product updates or bug fixes.  I don't know if that is the root cause of your problem, but it's the first thing I would look at.

Comment: @user9048121 Xamarin Studio 6.3 was the final release of Xamarin Studio (May 2017), I would update to the latest Visual Studio for Mac along with the matching Xamarin.Android / Xamarin.iOS / Mono and retry a clean build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Close project
2. Close Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio
3. Delete app (along with app data) from phone/emulator
4. Go to project directory, delete bin and obj folders
5. Open Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio
6. Re-deploy
7. Issue should be resolved now